# How do I stop my terminal from shrinking on focus shift when running on wayland

Tags: gnome-terminal, 22.04, wayland

22.04 wayland with gnome desktop.

Whenever I change focus between windows the terminal windows all shrink slightly.

Does not happen with xorg.

I believe it may have something to do with client side decorations.

Where can I find the setting for CSD under wayland?

I would like to toggle this feature on and off and see what happens and report back!

Comment: Do they permanently shrink (resize) or do they shrink momentarily as a desktop animation?

Comment: @mchid When they shrink they stay that way.  So permanently. You can of course manually resize the window back to where it was.

Answer (score 1):

This (or similar) bug continues to go on forever.

See e.g.

- https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7445
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mate-terminal/+bug/1878457
- https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/issues/350

And many others.

Workaround which works in the OS you are using: forget about Wayland (there are different workaround for other situations, e.g. switching theme, which don't work in Ubuntu 22.04).

Sigh.

Comment: In order to disable Wayland (and enable Xorg) just uncomment the line:

     `WaylandEnable=false`

in the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Comment: @tkow: if you double on title window, screen will be black screen and must reset machine.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for me in Dec of 2022 is to Menu -> View -> Normal Size

Comment: For me selection View -> Normal Size shrinks the window one step each time :-/